# Combining an array using Python and NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of the form:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
```

Is there a NumPy function which I can apply to these arrays to get the followng output?

```
[[1,4],[2,5][3,6]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
np.vstack((a,b)).T
```

returns

```
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

and

```
np.vstack((a,b)).T.tolist()
```

returns exactly what you need:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: I am hoping to keep it as a numpy array. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, `np.vstack((a,b)).T` returns a numpy array.