# Loading audio waveform files in python. ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, arrays, audio

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read

filepath = glob.glob('*.wav') #list

rate,data = [read(fp) for fp in filepath]
```

and I get :

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

but i can load only once a time.

like this:

```
rate,data = read('001.wav')
print rate
print data
```

and I get:

```
44100
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
```

How could I load the rate and data to two arrays, and if I do :

```
datas = [read(fp) for fp in filepath]
```

I will get :

```
[(44100, array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)), (44100, array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1], dtype=int16)), ..., (44100, array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16))]
```

or there is any way I can split the datas to rate and data after loading.

Thanks.

Comment: `[read(fp) for fp in filepath]` give more then two values.

Comment: what do you mean for more then two values?

Comment: Try this code on your interpreter: `>>>a, b = [1, 2, 3]` it give you same exception. because rhs have two variables `a` and `b` where lhs has three values to unpack `1`, `2`, `3`.

Comment: I think you need a better data structure!

Comment: How to fix the problem of my code, I can do rate,data = read('001.wav') and datas = [read(fp) for fp in filepath], but I can't do rate,data = [read(fp) for fp in filepath].
How could I load them use [read(fp) for fp in filepath] and puts data into two array? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split it after loading using the inverse zip function (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343/544059)):

```
In [13]: rate, data = zip(*datas)

In [14]: rate
Out[14]: (44100, 44100)

In [15]: data
Out[15]: (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1]))
```

I would say that this is an acceptable way to do it in this scenario, although I think using a more classical for loop, where you append to lists, without using list comprehension, would be cleaner:

```
rates = []
datas = []
for fp in filepath:
    rate, data = read(fp)
    rates.append(rate)
    datas.append(data)
```

The reason you got a `ValueError` in the first case is because you are unpacking a list of all tuples for each of your files (obviously more than 2 given the error message) into only two variables - rate and data.

Comment: Thank you.If I want to make (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])) to (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])),what should I done?

Comment: You can use `np.vstack(data)` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104245/python-numpy-combine-array), but you should try googling these things first, before asking here (I just searched for 'python combine arrays into matrix') :)

Comment: I only have the data array that contains (array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1], ..., dtype=int16), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)),if use np.vstack(data), I didn't know how to split data to each array then I can use np.vstack(each array) to combine it.

Comment: OK, I don't quite follow you, but in any case if you have some general problems understanding the data structures, I would first point you to read on the [numpy data structures](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial) and [list and tuples in Python](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). If you still have some specific questions after reading about them, open a new SO question. It is hard to read anything too detailed in these comments.

Comment: I was trying what you suggest, that numpy.vstack([datas]) will creat array like this: [[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)]].

Comment: In fact, I prefer to get like this :
(array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)).
My information is the datas is a list, so I need to add [], so numpy.vstack([datas]) would work without error,but I still try to find the way to make the array that I wish to use.Thanks.

Comment: This is a new SO question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254618/python-numpy-list-to-array-and-vstack

Thanks for all of the people who help me ever.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I see you got a good answer there already :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip(*x)` to format them into one list of rates and one list of the data lists.

```
raw_data = [read(fp) for fp in filepath]
rates, data = zip(*raw_data)
```

For example,

```
raw_data = zip(range(10), range(20, 30))
# [(0, 20), (1, 21), (2, 22), (3, 23), (4, 24), (5, 25), (6, 26), (7, 27), (8, 28), (9, 29)]

zip(*raw_data)
# [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29)]
```