# python: numpy list to array and vstack

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
filepath = glob.glob('*.wav')
rates = []
datas = []
for fp in filepath:
    rate, data = read(fp)
    rates.append(rate)
    datas.append(data)
```

I get a list 'datas' which is :

```
[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1], dtype=int16), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16),..., array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)]
```

and I use

```
new_array = numpy.vstack([datas])
```

to get the new_array :

```
[[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1], dtype=int16)
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
  ...
  array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)]]
```

But I really prefer one is :

```
(array([[ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  1],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   ...,        
   [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int16)
```

Which function should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you don't need the extra `[]` in the `vstack` call. Just try: `new_array = numpy.vstack(datas)`.

Comment: I try to remove `[]`, but I got a error message "`ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly.`"

Comment: Can you print `datas[0].shape`?

Comment: I print `datas[0].shape` , it's `(1308662,)` , and I print `datas[1].shape` , it's `(1306358,)`.

Comment: Well, you won't be able to vertically stack the data if each potential row has a different length. So first you need to sort out why the data have different lengths if they are conceptually supposed to be rows from the same matrix.

Comment: Thanks for you point out the length problem, I will figure out or fix the length to suitable.

Comment: If these arrays represent different sound files (in which case they would naturally have different lengths), you can also consider using a [pandas.DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) to store and manipulate them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me, so either the elements of `datas` are not flat arrays like your question suggests, the potential rows have different lengths (this turned out to be the reason, see comments), or perhaps you are using an older version that has a problem with a 1-dimensional object in `vstack`? (although I think that is unlikely)

```
In [14]: datas = [np.asarray([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), np.asarray([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])]

In [15]: datas
Out[15]: [array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])]

In [16]: datas[0].shape
Out[16]: (6,)

In [17]: np.vstack(datas)
Out[17]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```